# TextView right below another text

Tags: android, xml, listview

I want the city name to be displayed right below the Person name .

Here is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <TextView
   android:id="@+id/name"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="20sp"
   android:paddingTop="5dp"
   android:layout_weight="4"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:gravity="left"/>

<TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:id="@+id/city"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_gravity="left"
   android:layout_below="@+id/name"
   android:textSize="10dp"
   android:paddingLeft="35dp"
   android:paddingTop="15dp"
   android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Here is my image of layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUCZN.png) 
I want to display the city name right below the person name in the the unique `ListView` row

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

to

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the orientation like this

`android:orientation="vertical"`

Answer (score 0):

change your linear-layout `android:orientation`

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

to

```
 android:orientation="vertical"
```

Or you can use `RelativeLayout` like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Nilesh"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv1"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="city"
    android:id="@+id/tvcity"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvcity"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another linear layout but use vertical under your main linear layout. Then put both your first text view and the city name under that new linear layout.